# Binding Shift-Control-<letter> in tmux

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

I'm trying to bind `split-window` to `Ctrl-Shift-<some letter>` chord:

```
bind-key -n 'C-S-G' split-window -v                                                                      
bind-key -n 'C-S-B' split-window -h
```

This doesn't work. Why? Is there some way to use Ctrl-Shift modifier in tmux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Terminals support only a small set of Ctrl keys - @, a-z, [, ], \, ^ and function keys like F1 or Up.

You can bind M-G or M-B instead.